# Как в React Nativ Drawer запустить Screen с параметром?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Есть меню Drawer и мне нужно не просто запустить определённый Screen, а передать параметр.
Фактически будет грузится один и тот же скрин, а я буду передавать категорию, потом произойдёт подгрузка данных и эти данные отрисуются на одинаковом screen.
Фактически это кнопки в Drawer типа

- Политика
- Экономика
- Ещё что-то

И все грузят один и тот же screen, но со своим параметром.

Как такое реализовать?
(Я использую **expo Drawer Navigation**)

Answer (score 0):

Можно передавать параметр через навигацию:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/params

ещё можно использовать screenProps.